# MAUI Windows open console windows on release

Tags: maui-blazor

I am using MAUI blazor for developing an app. On debug build I can open chrome console window with shortcuts (CTRL+SHIFT+C), however on release I can't.

I have an issue that app crashes in release build and cannot find what the error is. How could I open chrome console window?

Comment: Can you open developer tools with F12?

Comment: Not in release build.

Comment: Hi@Miha Bogataj, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Yes, I just checked it and it does exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the MauiProgram.cs file in your project, which has code like this:

```
#if DEBUG
     builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
     builder. Logging. AddDebug();
#endif
```

This is to ensure that the Blazor Hybrid project is configured to support browser developer tools .You just need to remove the #if condition like this and it will be turned on in release mode too.

```
         builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
         builder. Logging. AddDebug();
```